# Android: Distributing an .apk file to test and doesn't work

Tags: android, mapkit, apk, android-install-apk

I am building an app using Eclipse. I got it to work on my device and I am trying to distribute it to a couple friends for them to test it on their phones, but I send them the same .apk I installed in my N1 and they aren't able to install it.

I tried sending them the version from inside the bin/ folder, extract it as an unsigned application or as a signed one, with the same results.

My SDK target is 1.6, so this isn't a problem, because both of them have 2.1+.

The main problem for me is that I have to test the application on real devices, since the emulators don't surf the net if I am connected to Internet through a proxy.

I use a Google keytool because I am using some Maps functionality, so I think that it could be in some way the source of the error, but I don't know what I have to do to fix this. Is it possible that the key is only valid for my device?

I thought that maybe the .apk wasn't working and I could only install it through my USB cable, but I was able to install my app from the same e-mail I sent to my friends.

Thanks in advance!!

**Edit:** I finally got hold of a friend's device and the error I got was the following, although I was able to install the app via Eclipse (USB cable).

> WARN/PackageInstaller(3317): Parse error when parsing manifest. Discontinuing installation

But if the manifest was wrong, I wouldn't be able to install and run the app, right?

Answer (score 1):

The Google Maps api has both [debug](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#getdebugfingerprint) and [release](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#getfingerprint) keys. So if you are using a debug key and generate a release apk, then the Maps api key will be incorrect and your map won't load any tiles.

You should make sure you are using the Maps Api key generated from your release keystore, and export the app in release mode.

Comment: And how can I know which one do I have? Because I remember I had to try different things to get my key, and I really don't know which one I finally got.


Also, could having the wrong key make the app not installable? And how come that in my device it does install and work perfectly?

How do I export my app in release mode? What I do is:
1) Right Click on Project Folder 2) Click on "Android Tools" option from menu. 3) Click on "Export Signed Application Package..." and my .apk generated in given application alias.

Comment: Exporting that way should be creating a signed "release" apk. The release key was generated using the md5 of the keystore you created with keytool. The debug key gets created using the md5 of debug.keystore which the ADT generates. The debug apk is what you are getting from your apps bin directory. An incorrect key shouldn't affect the install.

Answer (score 0):

whats the logcat output when the instalation fails ?
you can connect to the device using a usb port or use  a logcat app from the market

Comment: I don't know, because in my device it works. They get something like 'Wrong package' on a toast message.

Comment: as a friend to try it or borrow his device

Comment: Hi, I could get one of my friends to let me borrow his device, and I edited my answer to show the error I got via Logcat.